# How do you build a docker image and use it as the container for the next job in GitHub actions?

Tags: docker, github-actions

On my CI, I want to build a docker image once and then use the same image twice (or multiple times) for any following jobs, such as "test" and "lint".

```
  ╭─────────────╮
  │ build-image │
  ╰─────────────╯
        ⬇
 ╭──────╮ ╭──────╮
 │ test │ │ lint │
 ╰──────╯ ╰──────╯
```

It is possible to use a custom container using the [container attribute](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer). However, I'm unsure of how to make the image built in the "build-image" step accessible to that property.

What's the best approach to building an image and using it in the following jobs?

Comment: You can avoid the conflicts you are mentioning by tagging the image (built in a particular workflow run) with a unique tag and the reuse that tag in the next job. You can use `GITHUB_RUN_ID` runner provided environment variable as a unique tag. Please take a look at https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build the image in the first step and tag that image with the commit sha. Then, in the next step, load the container with the sha tag.

```
build-image:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
      with:
        registry: registry
        repository: user/repo/image-name
        tags: ${{ github.sha }}
test:
  needs: [build-image]
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  container:
    image: registry/user/repo/image-name:${{ github.sha }}
```